# Magento 2 - No minified files generated in admin

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, minify, minified-js

I've recently minified my website with a huge success, but this little thing. I don't get any generated .js files in the Admin panel, which causes the menu and a bunch of buttons not to work.

It generates just fine at the frontend. Css generates just fine too.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Once you switched to production mode, did you happen to run the setup and compile commands?
           
php bin/magento setup:upgrade , 
php bin/magento setup:di:compile , 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy